# Functions within R for dummy variables

Tags: r, function, dummy-variable

I'm wanting to create dummy variables for a few different columns in R. I can do this for the variable Disability with the code:

```
Disability <- model.matrix(~ Disability - 1,
                     transform(Dev_Mod, Disability = factor(paste(Disability, sep = "_"))))
```

Because I want to run this code multiple times for various variables I'd prefer to create a function for this, so I've written the function below:

```
dummy_vars <- function(Input1){
 output <- model.matrix(~ Input1 - 1,
                      transform(Dev_Mod, Input1 = factor(paste(Input1, sep = "_"))))
 return(output)
}
```

When I then run:

```
Disability <- dummy_vars("Disability")
```

I get the error

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
>   contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

I've tried this for multiple variables and I get the same error for each one.

I've checked and they definitely have 2 or more levels so I don't understand how to the fix the error.

Comment: You must substitute `Input1` with a name in the formula. If you provide a reproducible example we can show you how.

Comment: I thought that is what I was doing with :  Disability<-dummy_vars("Disability") The "Disability" would be Input1?

Comment: `"Disability"` is just a character string, not the name of a column in some unspecified data frame, your function knows nothing about that df. You could try making `Input1 = get("Disability")`. (I'm not sure that this works.)

Comment: I've found a different way of creating dummies for multiple variables at the same time using the code:- New_Dataset<-dummy.data.frame(dataset, sep="_") note that each variable within dataset will be changed to dummies so better to separate out the variables you want as dummies. Sep = "_" can be changed to whatever you want to be between the variable name and the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a different way of creating dummies for multiple variables at the same time using the code:-

```
New_Dataset<-dummy.data.frame(dataset, sep="")
```

Note that each variable within *dataset* will be changed to dummies, so it's better to separate out the variables you want as dummies.

```
Sep = ""
```

Can be changed to whatever you want to be between the variable name and the value of the variable.